# Incorporate Timestamp Variable into postgreSQL UPDATE statement

Tags: python, sql-update, pyodbc

I have the following snippet of code. It's supposed to update a row of data in my postgresql database. The issue I am running into is that the timestamp has a space between the date and time, following a typical timestamp format (which is giving a syntax error). If I weren't trying to incorporate a changing variable, I understand that I'd be able to just wrap it in " " and call it a day. How is it done using the bracket method of incorporating variables?

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE {} SET timestamp = {}, ememctotal = {}, busload = {}, dgload = {}, temp = {}, cvr = {} WHERE (year = {} AND month = {});".format(histTable, mTimestamp, mPeak, mBusLoad, mdgLoad, mTemp, mstatus, histYear, histMonth))
print ("Historical Peak Data update complete")
```

Comment: "How is it done using the bracket method of incorporating variables?" - You mean `.format()`? That's known as *Dynamic SQL* and is the wrong way to provide column values to an SQL statement. Do a web search on "SQL injection" for more information. TL;DR - Don't do that. Use a *parameterized query* instead.

Comment: Much appreciated for the info share. I was able to get it to work with that.